# Calling react native function within a class

Tags: function, react-native

I am implementing a pusher in my app in this way

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER_KEY', {
  cluster: 'ap1'
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert('New order received');
});

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orderData:[],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getOrders(); 
  }
  
  async getOrders() {
    // some code here
  }

}
```

As what you see in the code above, I am alerting `alert('New order received');` when the pusher is get triggered. But instead of alert, I want the function `getOrders()` to be called but not sure how to do that since it cannot be accessed by just specifying `getOrders()`.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be written within component

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

class Home extends React.Component {

    var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER_KEY', {
      cluster: 'ap1'
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) { 
        this.getOrders()
    });
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {
              orderData:[],
          };
    }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getOrders(); 
  }

  async getOrders() {
    // some code here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I moved only the binding code part in the constructor and call the `getOrders()` with `this`.

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER_KEY', {
  cluster: 'ap1'
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orderData:[],
    };

    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      this.getOrders(); 
    });
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getOrders(); 
  }
  
  async getOrders() {
    // some code here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch and save the orders inside the subscription as below.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
let self = this;
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
          //alert('New order received');
          self.state.orders= await self.getOrders();
});
```

Comment: I already put the binding inside the constructor and it's working fine now.